# How can I create multiple foreign keys to a table, from a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Assume that I have a table such as;

```
dbo.ACCOUNT_CHAR
strAccountID varchar(50),
strCharID1 varchar(50),
strCharID2 varchar(50),
strCharID3 varchar(50)
```

and one more table, which holds character data;

```
dbo.USERDATA
strCharID varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY
... and some other irrelevant stuff.
```

I want to create foreign key between `strCharID1`,`strCharID2`,`strCharID3` to `strCharID` column in `dbo.USERDATA` table, so I can benefit from on update and on delete events. I want to cascade on update, set null on delete.

I tried to create these foreign keys but it gives me multiple cascade paths error. Is there a way to work around this problem, or I have to create a row for each character in `account_char` table and remove the `strCharID2` and `strCharID3`?

Comment: This isn't good. What you should be doing is creating a junction table and have UserDataId and Account_CharId in that table.

Comment: Anytime you see a table with field names like strCharID1, strCharID2, etc. then you know that the table needs to be normalized. This is a poor design. You need a child table to contain the strCharID records. SQL server is right to tell you not crete foriegn keys with multiple paths. THis whole design is seriously flawed. Incidentally cascade delete and update are generally things that you do not want to do in database of any size. Think about what happens if you need to delete a million records from the parent table.

Comment: I know, these tables belong to a legacy system, which working cooperatively with some old software. I wanted to re-design the database as well but the limitations kept me away.